# What are some good photography related DVDs?

Tags: learning, dvd

I can recommend David Noton's [Chasing The Light](http://www.leefilters.com/camera/news/articles/ref:N48035D8818398/).

Comment: This should really be a community wiki question.

Comment: This is worded pretty broadly; do you have any specific type of photography in mind?

Comment: @jfklein13 - deliberately so, I'm hoping this will be useful for all types of photographers...

Answer (score 2):

James Nachtwey in "[War Photographer](http://www.war-photographer.com)".

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Sandy Puc' resources for studying child and family portraiture.  They're priced for people who want to go professional in that area.  Without a mentor, it's hard to find a better source for posing and tricks for working with kids.

She sells her materials through

http://www.sandysworlduniversity.com/

Click on Campus Store.

I can recommend the Tour DVDs as a start.  I attended the 2010 Family Tour, and have watched the Bellies and Babies and Teens to Tots tour videos from previous years. All good stuff, but all aimed at professional photographers or someone who wants to be in that business.